# adding WHERE clause to SQL Server Query panel

Tags: sql-server

I'm in the Server Explorer and on the table name, I right-click on "Select Top 1000 Rows". The query panel show the SQL generated as

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [...] ,[....] , [....]
FROM [filename].[dbo].[TableName]
```

Now I want to add a simple WHERE clause.

I tried adding it like this:

```
WHERE [ColumnName] == 11
```

It's not working. I know this is a very basic question but I don't have much experience with working on SQL Server directly.

How do I fix the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the double == sign SQL terminology is to use only a single =

From your example:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [...] ,[....] , [....]
FROM [filename].[dbo].[TableName]
WHERE [ColumnName] = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

C# uses double equal ("==") for conditional checks, in sql it is single "=" for predicates.